# nest api temperature change source

Tags: nest-api

is is possible to tell what source changed the temperature through the api, human/scheduled/another client?

I noticed the nest app history lists how the temperature was set and didn't notice anything in the api that says that.

Answer (score 0):

That level of info is not in the API, but like you said the nest app will, show which client actually initiated the change.